# Deleted permissions for owners on Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, administration, folder

I was trying to delete permission of all users to a specific folder on SharePoint.

I accidentally deleted all permissions even for owners (myself and others) and cannot see the documents at all now.

The documents are still there but no one from the team, not even me can see them. I contacted IT as they may have more admin rights than myself. Can they restore previous access rights or assign owner to me and then I can add the team again?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to grant you the owner access on SharePoint site or document library using the Site Collection Administrator (SCA) account.

User the Site Collection Administrator (SCA) access on SharePoint online site can see all the lists, libraries, folders, documents, etc. in the SharePoint site even when the permission inheritance is broken and item level permissions are used.

Contact your IT department team, they can identify who is the Site Collection Administrator (SCA) for your SharePoint site.

You can request IT team or Site Collection Administrator (SCA) of your site to grant you owner (full control) access then you can add the other users / team again to permissions settings.

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @ChristieKon! I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Please [accept this response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.